# Split string in Python while keeping the line break inside the generated list

Tags: python, python-3.x

As simple as it sounds, can't think of a straightforward way of doing the below in Python.

```
my_string = "This is a      test.\nAlso\tthis"
list_i_want = ["This", "is", "a", "test.", "\n", "Also", "this"]
```

I need the same behaviour as with `string.split()`, i.e. remove any type and number of whitespaces, but excluding the line breaks `\n` in which case I need it as a standalone list item.

How could I do this?

Comment: First split it at newline, and insert a newline between each resulting string. Then split each non-newline string at whitespace.

Comment: It makes total sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Split String using Regex findall()

```
import re

my_string = "This is a      test.\nAlso\tthis"
my_list = re.findall(r"\S+|\n", my_string)

print(my_list)
```

**How it Works:**

- "\S+": "\S" = non whitespace characters. "+" is a greed quantifier so it find any groups of non-whitespace characters aka words
- "|": OR logic
- "\n": Find "\n" so it's returned as well in your list

### Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test.', '\n', 'Also', 'this']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that works but is definitely not efficient/pythonic:

```
my_string = "This is a      test.\nAlso\tthis"
l = my_string.splitlines() #Splitting lines
list_i_want = []
for i in l:
    list_i_want.extend((i.split())) # Extending elements in list by splitting lines
    list_i_want.extend('\n') # adding newline character 

list_i_want.pop() # Removing last newline character
print(list_i_want)
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test.', '\n', 'Also', 'this']
```